# Python dict ordering

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a web application that expects a json file with the correct ordering of the json objects in a python list. It should be ordered x, y but no matter what I try, the values always return as y, x.

```
list: [{'y': 0.0, 'x': 1360633172168}, {'y': 0.0, 'x': 1360633172168}, ...
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to reorder these before writing the values out to the console?

```
        label = ["x", "y"]
        sen = []
        for i in average:
            now = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
            l = now, i[0]
            sen.append(l)
        x = [dict(zip(label, e)) for e in sen]
```

I have tried several approaches to this and I get the same results every time.

Adam

Comment: 1. This is not enough code to reproduce the error. 2. Don't use `list` as a variable name in Python.

Comment: you have a major design flaw: json object name/value pairs are not ordered. http://www.json.org/

Comment: just as Python `dict` keys :)

Comment: @Triptych list was just from the output from the PyDev console. Its not actually the var name.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Ugh...I was hoping to correct this in python rather than digging in to the javascript graphing library I am using.

Comment: @AdamEstrada now you have two problems.

Comment: uhm... the JS standard doesn't require the implementation to remember the order..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it's clear that the consumer is broken

Comment: @AdamEstrada: The point is, as Karoly Horvath keeps saying, JSON objects are not ordered. The problem isn't in your Python code, or in your JS code; there is no correct code on either side that will guarantee order within JSON objects. You have to change it to something ordered, e.g., `[["x", 1360633172168], ["y", 0.0]]]` instead of `{"x": 1360633172168, "y": 0.0}`.

Comment: Also, if your "JSON" really has single-quoted strings like the sample code, it's got another problem—that's not actually JSON at all.

Comment: I get it now...Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: You wrote "no matter what I try, the values always return as y, x". If you upgrade to the latest version of Python (3.3) you'll find the order is no longer even stable, it is randomised between runs of your code.

Answer (score 6):

The only solution would be to pass along an array, or store the order python side, of keys that are sorted and access the dict using that.

JSON:

```
{
    "order": ["x", "y"],
    "d": {x: 34, y:36}
}
```

PYTHON:

```
for key in order:
    print d[key]
```

This will allow you to go through the dict keys in the proper order.

Dicts are a form of [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and therefore they do not preserve key order.

Comment: The problem isn't really that `dict` is a form of hash map, and therefore unordered, but that JSON objects themselves are unordered. There is no way to "preserve the order of a JSON object", because there is no such order. But your two solutions are both correct, so +1.

Comment: I don't know how to say this online without it sounding sarcastic(just take my word it isn't) what would be the point/concern of preserving the order of a json encoded object? And if truly required assuming the side that generates the JSON and the side receiving have the concept of ordered dicts you could write a json encoder that preserves the order.

Comment: Well, anything that's a good use case for `OrderedDict` is probably also a good use case for a JSON equivalent, right? It's true that 95% of the time when someone thinks they need an ordered dictionary they really don't, but 95% isn't 100%.

Comment: Meanwhile, it feels a bit strange to be arguing in support of your answer against you, but really, if you want to serialize an ordered dictionary (whether Python `OrderedDict`, C++ `map`, whatever) in JSON, the array-of-pairs and dict-plus-separate-key-order-array solutions in your answer are almost always going to be a better answer than a custom not-quite-JSON dialect.

Comment: No argument intended ;) Just seeing if there was a use case I hadn't considered for an ordered json serializer. And the point you brought up is very true if you have a concept like an `OrderedDict` it's just as valid to have ordered JSON.

Comment: I found the rationale for `OrderedDict` in [PEP 372](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/#rationale). One reason is to port from/interact with Ruby and PHP (where the equivalent base type is ordered), so you might want to use an order-preserving JSON format instead of just an object to communicate with a Ruby or PHP service. Another is that XML languages may attach a meaning to attribute orders, so if you want to convert XML to JSON you may want to use an order-preserving conversion. So, now I feel better than just saying "There's gotta be some reason, right? Maybe?"

Comment: +1 for finding a couple reasons. I did not know Ruby and PHP's equivalents are ordered by default, seems odd in and of its self. However due to my lack of experience in either of those, do people actually rely on that behaviour/develop code in which the order actually does matter or is it just something that exists but doesn't really matter? The XML one makes the most sense to me, I could see if you wanted to do that or perhaps someone who's crazy might want to make their HTML in JSON and build a converter. Neat.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look into [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
In [9]: d = collections.OrderedDict()

In [10]: d['x'] = 1360633172168

In [11]: d['y'] = 0.0

In [12]: d
Out[12]: OrderedDict([('x', 1360633172168), ('y', 0.0)])

In [13]: d['x']
Out[13]: 1360633172168

In [14]: d['y']
Out[14]: 0.0
```

Comment: That won't help here, because there's no order to preserve in the first place.

Comment: You can guess/hope/check that `json.dumps(d)` preserves the order, so this is helpful if it's not possible to fix the broken parser at the consumer.

Comment: @gnibbler: But a parser that ignores the order is _not_ broken, it's doing the right thing. A JSON object is intended to be parsed into a JavaScript `object` (hence the name), or a similar type like a Python `dict`. Even some libraries in other languages that use ordered mapping types (like a C++ map) _intentionally_ scramble the order to make sure your code doesn't make bad assumptions.

Comment: @abarnert, but sometimes in real life we just need to make things work. We can't always control broken components.

Comment: @gnibbler: Well, looking at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps), if `sort_keys` is true you get the keys in sorted order, otherwise in arbitrary order. From [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/json/encoder.py#l432), that arbitrary order seems to be the `dict` order as returned by `iteritems`, so it should work. At least with CPython 2.7's standard `json`. But I wouldn't trust that.

Comment: @gnibbler: However, in 2.7+, there is actually a documented way to deal with this. In `loads`, use `object_pairs_hook`; in `dumps`, use `sort_keys`, which means you need to DSU the keys (and the undecorate step has to be inside the rendering) because there's no `key` function parameter. It's almost as if they deliberately made this difficult as a reminder that if you think you want this, you probably don't… Or, more likely, `sort_keys` without `key` was good enough for the one case somebody needed, so that's what got added. At any rate, just saying "use `OrderedDict`" isn't quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have keys in a specific order you will need to construct your "JSON" output manually as neither Python's `dict` nor the `json` module support fixed key ordering.

Comment: Constructing the object manually doesn't help, because JSON objects are not ordered anyway. If you want to use a not-quite-JSON language as interchange, you can write custom code on both sides to construct and parse those not-quite-JSON objects, but really, it's better to pass JSON arrays of arrays, or keep an array of key orders. (In other words, the two solutions in dennmat's answer.)